# Problem size and input pre-process costs in finding time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I read different topics about time complexity on algorithms. I try to understand and learn how to analyze algorithms, but I still have some concerns. Therefore, I hope that this topic will help to make them clear.

Here is a problem:

> Give an integer **n** (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^18). Removing digits at any positions from **n** to create new numbers. Find the largest cube number from those numbers including **n**. If there is no any cube number, return **-1**.

And below is a solution.

```js
let maxCubeNum = -1;

function isCubeNumber(num) {
  let x = Math.round(Math.pow(num, 1 / 3), 0);
  return x * x * x === num;
}

// generate the subset numbers from n's digits with recursion
function findCubeNumber(digits) {
  if (digits.length == 0)
    return [0];

  // recursively find all subsets without the last digit
  let parts = findCubeNumber(digits.slice(0, -1));

  let nums = [];
  parts.forEach(part => {
    // case 1: with the last digit
    let num1 = part * 10 + digits.slice(-1)[0];
    // case 2: without the last digit
    let num2 = part;

    if (isCubeNumber(num1))
      if (num1 > maxCubeNum)
        maxCubeNum = num1;

    if (num2 > 0 && isCubeNumber(num2))
      if (num2 > maxCubeNum)
        maxCubeNum = num2;

    nums.push(num1);
    nums.push(num2);
  });

  return nums;
}

function findNumbers(n) {
  maxCubeNum = -1
  let digits = [];

  // split n to digits
  while (n > 0) {
    digits.unshift(n % 10);  // insert to the first position of the list
    n = (n - n % 10) / 10;   // integer division by 10
  }

  // generate subset numbers and find the max cube number from those numbers
  findCubeNumber(digits);

  return maxCubeNum;
}

let ans = findNumbers(4125);
document.write(ans);
```

Note that, my point is analyzing the above algorithm to find its time complexity. I am not looking for a better algorithm.

## My questions

### 1. What is the problem size in the above algorithm?

It is `n` or `log10(n)` (`value` or `length of n`)?

I'm quite confused since the problem can be resolved with a naive solution as following:

```
findCubeNumber(n) {
  for(i=n; i>0; i--)
    if (i is_subset n and is_cube_num(i))
      return i;

  return -1;
}
```

In this case, the problem size is apparently `n`. By this way, the above algorithm has size of `log10(n)` as it is based on the length of the number `n`.

But if we consider the length of the input number as the problem size, the pseudo-code's size will be `10^n`.

These will lead to different results of time complexity. Then, which of them is the problem size?

### 2. When we talk about the time complexity of an algorithm, we would include costs of pre-processing input data or not?

For example, in the above algorithm, I use a while-loop to split number `n` into digits. would I count it as a part of calculating time complexity?

I have seen few topics around, one uses built-in function in a particular programming language to convert the number to string, considers it as a constant cost, and ignores it. Is that right?

### 3. What is the time complexity of the above algorithm?

#### a. If the problem size is the length of number `n`, the costs are respectively:

`2`   - the first two assignments in findNumbers()

`a*n` - a while-loop splitting number `n` into digits, a is a constant and represents to inner operators in while-loop of findNumbers().

The time complexity of the recursive function would be:

`T(n) = 1 + T(n - 1) + 2^n`

Where,

`1` - The comparing operator to stop recursive function

`T(n - 1)` - call itself with the size reducing 1.

`2^n` - forEach loop steps which creating numbers by a combination of digits. Each digit will have two states: `present` (with the digit) and `absent` (without the digit).

By induction: T(n) = 2^n * b + n + c (b, c are constants)

Then the time complexity of the entire algorithm,

T(n) = 2 + a*n + 2^n * b + n + c = T(2^n + n) = **T(2^n)**

#### b. If the problem size is the value of number `n`, then

T(n) = 2 + a*log10(n) + 2^log10(n)*b + log10(n) + c = T(2^log10(n)) = T(2^log2(n)) = **T(n)**

Which is the right answer? or both of them wrong?

Please help me to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The problem size: N, in both cases. Think about it, what is the problem size for? It helps you determine what has a direct influence on the complexity. It should be independent from the algorithm you use, it describes the problem, not your solution. Then you have the complexity described in big-O notation to indicate how many calculations need to be done based on the problem size. If you put N in the big-O, your problem size is N.

You can set the problem size to whatever you want as long as you are consistent with it. You can say that the problem size is M = log10(N). That will change the big-O complexity, now it should depend on the problem size, that is M. If you do it this way, do not use log10(N) in the big-O notation.

O(N) = O(10^M), choose one notation and stick to it.

2. Usually the programming languages' methods do not have a constant time complexity. Their complexity should be stated in the language's reference. For example, 99% of the programming languages has a sort function that sorts the array/list/collection in O(n log n) time. If you have the code that sorts the array like that:

   ```
    sort(array)
   ```

would you say it's O(1), because you used a method provided by the language? Think about why do you even determine the complexity. It is for the person who will use your code in the future, so he can easily say how long it will execute. If you tell him that the code is O(1), he will be really disappointed if he puts an array of length 10^18 and waits till the end of his life for your O(1) code to finish. The language's functions' should be included in the complexity.

The preprocessing should be included in the complexity of a routine. If you have a preprocessing part at the beginning, normally you'd say the complexity is O(preprocessing) + O(the rest), at least if the preprocessing part takes more time than the rest. You can also merge them together if you want so. In your case you could write O(logN) + O(N) or just O(N), both are fine.

3. First calculation:
   I wouldn't use 'n' in the formulas since it represents the lenght of a number 'n' (naming conflict). The estimate is correct, the complexity is O(2^M) where M = log(N).

The second one is also correct.

Both of the equations calculate the same thing, but be careful about the notation. In the first one 'n' is the number of digits, in the second one 'n' is the number. You can use any of those two notations as long as you don't mix them up. Just stick to one.